# Kendo UI Grid - serverside pagination with PHP

Tags: php, pagination, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can anyone assist in getting my Grid working so that it pulls and displays 50 rows at a time? It currently displays 50 rows but does not show any page numbering.  I have included a total of 120 in the datasource but do not know where to go from here.   How do I display the page numbers and pass `$start, $limit` variables to my query is is getting the data?

Where it should say "1 - 50 of 120 items" it says "No items to display"

Im stuck. :0(

```
var mydata =  {"data":[

        <?php foreach ($data_arr as $data){ ?>
            { "id": "<?php echo $data['id']; ?>",  "name":"<?php echo $data['surname'] . ', ' . $data['firstname']; ?>",  "company": "<?php echo $data['company']; ?>",   "Email": "<?php echo $data['email']; ?>"},
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
        ]       , "total": <?=$total?>};
>       
>       
>         $("#grid").kendoGrid({
>             dataSource: {
>                 data: mydata.data,
>                 schema: {
>                   total: "total",
>                     model: {
>                         fields: {
>                             id: { type: "number" },
>                             name: { type: "string" },
>                             company: { type: "string" },
>                             email: { type: "email" }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 },
>                 pageSize: 50
>             },            serverPaging: true,
>             scrollable: false,
>             sortable: true,
>             filterable: true,             selectable: "row",
>           detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html()),
>             detailInit: detailInit,
>             pageable: {refresh: true,},           
>             columns: [
>                 {field:"id",title: "ID",filterable: false},
>                 {field: "name",title: "Name"}, 
>                 {field: "company",title: "Company"}, 
>                 {field: "email",title: "Email"}             
>             ]                 
>         });
```

Then there's the server side PHP which does not seem to be getting anything from the URL all :

> //get current page from URL
>   $get = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
>   parse_str($get);
>   if(isset($page)){
>   $start = $page;
>
> $limit = $pagesize;
>   }
>   $admin = new Admin();
>
> $count_data = $admin->countRows();  //brings back 120
>   $mydata= $admin->getRows($start=0,$limit=50);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid's data source isn't configured for server binding. You must configure the [transport.read](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read) option to provide the url which will return the paged data. The data source will post the page and pagesize.

Here is an online demo you can check: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.   The page numbering is now working, however, since carrying out these changes it seems to have broken OnClick functions I had.  Any ideas off the top of your head why that could be?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get variables from the url:

```
$start = $_GET['page'];
$limit = $_GET['pagesize'];
```

That should work

Comment: these don't exist in the URL, I think that's the issue.  There are no page links / buttons being displayed and I assusme they would pass these vars to the URL and then it wold all work.

Comment: @LeeTee You can test that by putting it in the url yourself: ?page=0&pagesize=50

Comment: yeah I get that.  The problem is the grid isn't showing any page numbering, so amending the URL myself isn't an option.

Comment: I have a total of 120 rows and want to bring them out in 50's, it  brings out the first 50 but does not show any page numbering.  Where it should say 1 - 50 of 120 items it says "No items to display"